# Ipa file only installs on some iOS devices

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, ipa, diawi

I'm facing this issue where my `.ipa` file installs and runs perfectly on some physical iOS devices. It however, just remains darkened (the logo) after installing on some iOS devices. Now, I've checked the architecture and the build covers all the necessary architectures. I've checked the min sdk too and it more than covers what I need. So I for one am baffled as to why my flutter application only runs on certain iPhones (physical). It runs on all simulators tho.

Photo of darkened logo:

[image]

What happened was it became dark and started installing like any iOS app would but after installing, it just remained darkened and was not-clickable. I'm using [diawi](https://www.diawi.com/) to generate the link to help the iPhones to download the `ipa`.

Does anyone know what might be a potential cause for this ?

Comment: Those device's UDID might not be added into the profile that you are selecting to create iPA file. Please check with your Apple Developer account.

Comment: @manishsharma93 alright, I'll check it out soon, thanks !

Comment: @Rajdeep kindly check my Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be few reasons where ipa file should not work on few devices where it works on other ones. Here is the listed below :

1. Device in which you are trying to install, UDID is not added to the provisioning profile
2. Link you created for ipa file installation gets corrupted
3. Site which are using for creating iPa installation link contains installation limits
4. Installation link gets expired after few days due to free version you are using

**Suggestions :**

- If you are using http://diawi.com try it with Login. So it will give you more time before expiration of the link
- Try https://www.installonair.com  for making links for installation. Its damn easy to use & works well.

Hope this helps everyone.

Answer (score 2):

You must add Device UDID in provisioning profile to get installed on it. If you are making build link via Diawi. You can see all added UDID there.